# Are fragmented IP used nowadays?

Tags: network-programming, ip, tcp

Linux with default settings rejects ip fragmented SYN by sending RST immediately, also I tried antiddos cloud services and hosting providers with ddos protection, looks like they completely ignore such packets.

I'm writing antiddos filter that will deal with 10gbit using netmap and wondering is it safe to silently ignore fragmented ip packets, or they may appear from legitimate users? Because I have no idea how to effectively reassemble and filter such packets on 10gbit speed

Comment: As I can see IP layer fragmentation is used for big udp packet, but is it used in tcp?

Answer (score 0):

Any node or router can fragment an IPv4 PDU. It's weird that a TCP SYN message could be fragmented as, without options its length will be 40 Octets. However, you may want to take a look at [RFC 7413: TCP Fast Open](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7413), which allows SYN and SYN/ACK messages convey data.

In IPv6 only the source node can fragment a PDU.

Comment: Any router can, but is it usual thing in practice? But you gave me a good idea that SYN won't be fragmented anyway, and other packets will be forwarded to kernel network stack that knows how to reassemble them. TCP has MSS option to control packet size, so shouldn't be fragmented. Supporting fastopen is impossible when you try to deal with 10gbit on a x86 server, currently I use preallocated hashtable storing small states, for SYN fopen data dynamic size buffers are required, mem copy, management is too expensive at such speed.  windows doesn't support it so it useless for http sites

Comment: @user1940679, I don't understand the relation between 10gbitE and fastopen. Are you saying this because you can have a huge MTU with jumbo frames? Otherwise, that's just a layer 1 thing and should not affect upper layers. I didn't understand your last comment, are you creating your own TCP implementation or are you implementing a TCP connection manager that later passes the control to the OS' TCP?

Comment: I'm implementing synproxy-like filter that sits before OS network stack and forwards valid packets to kernel. Accepting any additional data in syn is too cpu/memory expensive if system will be hit by syn with random sized data you will need to store this data somewhere for some time, this adds lot of complexity and experimental tcp extension that even not supported by 99% of users not worht it.  Reassembling fragmented packets is also expensive task if you are flooded with lot of random ip packets, so I'm asking is it safe to ignore them since looks like 99.9% tcp packets aren't fragmented.